# How to retrieve a twilio chat channel history - all conversation that happened in a channel

Tags: twilio, chat, channel

My team is trying to create a chat application using Twilio Chat api.
Can anyone please suggest how to get the chat history from twilio channelafter a chat session is completed. We want to store the chat conversation in our database.
I want to download the entire conversation that happened between two people in a private twilio channel before i delete the channel permanently. Is twilio providing this functionality?

Thanks,
TT

Comment: Did you got the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Got some help from Twilio support. Sharing it here for everyone who is interested.

"You should be able to retrieve all the messages in a channel via our REST API. We also have a C# helper library (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) and you can find the exact code and endpoint here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/api/messages?code-sample=code-list-all-messages&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=5.x "

Thank you David (Twilio Support)